# Sharepoint 2010: Can't create a folder in a custom list

Tags: sharepoint, directory, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to create folders in a set of custom lists I've created. However, when I try to do this, the New Folder button in the Ribbon is disabled. I read up on the matter; and this lead me to look to enable folder creation in List Settings -> Advance Settings. However, there doesn't seem to be an option to enable folder creation on the page. It shouldn't be a permission related issue; as I created the lists; and I'm also an admin on the farm.

I could use a document library; but we will not be uploading documents to the list; so this is more then I need.

What are my options, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folders are not supported by custom lists, as custom lists are used more like a database. Instead using grouping to group the list items according to a certain column value, such as Date, Created By, or a custom column.